# Connecting python to SharePoint

Tags: python, office365

Looking to connect to SharePoint via python with the simple script below

```
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential

def get_sharepoint_context_using_user():
 
    # Get sharepoint credentials
    sharepoint_url = 'https://abc.sharepoint.com'

    # Initialize the client credentials
    user_credentials = UserCredential("johndoe@gmail.com", "fakePass123")

    # create client context object
    ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url).with_credentials(user_credentials)

    return ctx
```

The code runs without any errors but when I call the **get_sharepoint_context_using_user()** later on in another section of my script I receive the following error

```
NameError: name 'get_sharepoint_context_using_app' is not defined
```

There is also a red "x" on the line with
`ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_url).with_credentials(user_credentials)` saying **client context is undefined.**

Any ideas?

Comment: you should try using the shareplum module, it works fine from my experience

Comment: @zanga I was attempting to use shareplum but I got the following error when doing so **Exception: ('Error authenticating against Office 365. Error from Office 365:', "AADSTS50053: The account is locked, you've tried to sign in too many times with an incorrect user ID or password.")**